# How to cut a rect out in Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, clip

I create a RoundRec.

`canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, 100, 10), 7, 7, paint);`

But I only want the top two round corners, so I need to cut the half bottom Rect(0, 0, 0, 5) out, and just left the half top side.

What should I do?

Comment: And what are you gonna do with such an object?

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here:
[How to Cut a Bitmap](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/640058/How-to-cut-a-bitmap)

The second:

> Rect srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, origialBitmap.getWidth() / 2, origialBitmap.getHeight() / 2);

Should be **destRect**!.

Just remember that the "destRect" must have coordinates equals to

"0, 0, destinationBitmap.getWidth(), destinationBitmap.getHeight()"

and not have same "srcRect" coords. The example in the link is a little weird because it use the "originalBitmap" to get the "destRect", but the "destRect" doesn't belong to the "originalBitmap", instead it belong to the "destinationBitmap" (or "cutBitmap"). So this "destRect" will have, if you want to draw the picture inside all "destinationBitmap":

left = 0x0, top = 0x0, right = destinationBitmap.getWidth(), bottom = destinationBitmap.getHeight().

So using the "destinationBitmap" instead the "originalBitmap" is a little more meaningfull because "srcRect" belong to "originalBitmap" size / coords and "destRect" belong to "destinationBitmap" size / coords.

My code:

```
Bitmap barcodeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.round(Math.abs(rect.left - rect.right)), Math.round(Math.abs(rect.top - rect.bottom)), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas cutCanvas = new Canvas(barcodeBitmap);
        Rect srcRect = new Rect(Math.round(rect.left), Math.round(rect.top), Math.round(rect.right), Math.round(rect.bottom));
        Rect destRect = new Rect(0x0, 0x0, barcodeBitmap.getWidth(), barcodeBitmap.getHeight());
        cutCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, destRect, null);
```

(For ones who doesn't know: 0x0 = 0 in hexadecimal. I always prefer hex instead of dec for numerical constants. More fc*ng exotic code and less work for tha compiler (in C/C++, don't know here in Java :/ ) )

This is inside a "TakePictureCameraSourceCallback" to draw a red rect bounding a Barcode after you scanned it. 
If you are building something similar P.M. me and I will give you all Activity / Fragment codes to get the barcode using Google Vision (you can search it in GitHub, there is one which use CameraSource instances to show the bounding around the barcode until u are scanning for it. 
Anyway I have implemented an Activity which returns directly the cutted barcode bitmap, so if you don't wanna do all the work just pm. I won't ask for maneyz :P )

> **Math you will need:**
>   if u have points with x/y coordinates you can get distance between left-point and right-point by doing:
>
> Dlr = sqrt( sqr(x1 - x2) + sqr(y1 - y2) )
>
> You know "sqrt -> Square Root" and "sqr -> Square" so "^2" so "x1 *
>   x1".
>
> if you have just 1 coordinates, like how "Rect" works, that's mean u
>   have 4 values (left, right, top, bottom) that are Lines, so to get
>   distance between left and right you need to do the Absolute value of
>   the difference (same for top / bottom, ecc):
>
> Math.abs(left - right)
>
> Just remember that "Rect" use "float" values for coords, so you need
>   to  "Math.round(left)" and maybe add 1 because "Math.round" will round
>   "<0.4" to "0", so you will need "0.4" of the originalBitmap.

```
public static Bitmap cutBitmap(Bitmap originalBitmap, int srcLeft, int srcTop, int srcRight, int srcBottom){
    return cutBitmap(originalBitmap, new Rect(srcLeft, srcTop, srcRight, srcBottom));
}

public static Bitmap cutBitmap(Bitmap originalBitmap, Rect srcRect){
    Bitmap cutted = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.abs(srcRect.left - srcRect.right), Math.abs(srcRect.top - srcRect.bottom), originalBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas cutCanvas = new Canvas(cutted);
    Rect destRect = new Rect(0x0, 0x0, cutted.getWidth(), cutted.getHeight());
    cutCanvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, srcRect, destRect, null);
    return cutted;
}
```

These are the Generic Utils functions you can implement in your library and call to cut how you want the image.

So the code above about the Barcode become:

```
ImageUtils.cutBitmap(bitmap, Math.round(rect.left), Math.round(rect.top), Math.round(rect.right), Math.round(rect.bottom));
```

Byez, nice c0ding
z3r0

Answer (score -3):

If i understand correctly, you want to draw a rectangle where only the top corners are rounded?

you can create a [custom shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) using xml.

In res/drawable you'll have an xml (let's call it "myCustomRect") that'll look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

<corners
        android:topLeftRadius="7"
        android:topRightRadius="7"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0" />
<size
        android:width="100"
        android:height="10"/>
<solid
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

You'll specify the shape in your layout:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myId"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/muCustomRect"/>
```

I didn't test all of this so you may have to debug a little yourself.

Comment: btw, you're lucky i didn't see that this was a duplicate thread.